# How to set the portrait and landscape height (percent) in constraint layout but not losing the constraint?

Tags: android, android-layout

I did this code but the image pushed out the work space

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constrainsalah"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintPortraitHeight_percent="0.15"
        app:layout_constraintLandscapeHeight_percent="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question correctly,
Change the

```
app:layout_constraintPortraitHeight_percent="0.15"
app:layout_constraintLandscapeHeight_percent="0.2"
```

to

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
```

and add this on the line

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" android:fillViewport="true"
```

Copy this code instead

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constrainsalah"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" android:fillViewport="true">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: well thats fast and working, thank you sir

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Would it be too much to ask for a little more explanation? Answer with explanations are more valuable to a community of learners.

Comment: I do not really understand the rule here sir, which is why Im trying to answer it as short as possible to avoid devote. You can ask what you want to know and I will help my best to answer it, if its not clear, ask more.